# Find rows in a table based on the existance of two different rows in a 1:N-related table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a table Clients, with a field ClientID, and that client has orders that are loaded in another table Orders, with foreign key ClientID to link both.

A client can have many orders (1:N), but orders have different types, described by the field TypeID.

Now, I want to select the clients that have orders of a number of types. For instance, the clients that have orders of type 1 and 2 (both, not one or the other).

How do I build this query? I'm really at lost here.

EDIT: Assume I'm on SQL Server.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Edited to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is query upon the assumption that TypeId can be either 1 or 2. This will return ClientId that have both a Type1 and Type2 no matter how many of them.

```
Select ClientId, COUNT(distinct TypeId) as cnt
from tblOrders o
group by ClientId
Having COUNT(distinct TypeId) >= 2
```

`COUNT(distinct TypeId)` is how this really works. It will count the distinct number of TypeId's for a particular ClientId. If you had say 5 different Types, then change the condition in the Having Clause to 5

This is a small sample DataSet

```
ClientId    TypeId
1              1
1              2
1              2
2              2
2              1
3              1
3              1
```

Here is the resulting Query, it will exclude client 3 because it only has orders with Type1

Result Set

```
ClientId    cnt
1            2
2            2
```

If you have many different TypeId's, but only want to check Type1 and Type2 put those Id's in a where clause

```
where TypeId in (1,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution:

```
select * from clients c
 where exists (select 1 from orders o where typeid = 1 and o.clientid = c.clientid)
   and exists (select 1 from orders o where typeid = 2 and o.clientid = c.clientid)
   and exists (select 1 from orders o where typeid = 3 and o.clientid = c.clientid)
   -- additional types ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [INTERSECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188055.aspx) which will give the intersection of the resultsets.